# why npm start throws an ENOENT error when trying to start my react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I've created only two projects with npx create-react-app. The first one started perfectly with npm start. Yesterday I created a second project and when I tried to start it with npm start throws the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\divah_000\AppData\Local\Temp;C:'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2552:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\divah_000\Desktop\ReactCourse\lists_in_react\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\divah_000\Desktop\ReactCourse\lists_in_react\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\divah_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp;C:'
}
```

The thing is that now my first project also throws the same error.

I tried uninstall node and reinstall but it shows the same error, also cleaned the cache for node but I keep getting the same error.
My node and npm version are:

```
npm --version
9\.3.1
```

```
node --version
v18.14.0
```

Comment: The path to tmp directory doesn't look right. Try to run `node -e "require('node:fs').realpath(require('os').tmpdir(), console.log)"` - This is the code from `tmp-dir` npm package. Which fails in your case https://github.com/sindresorhus/temp-dir/blob/main/index.js#L4

Comment: I see! thank you. When I run `node -e "require('node:fs').realpath(require('os').tmpdir(), console.log)"` the same error appears, and also the same wrong temp directory is showed.  For some reason my temp enviroment variable had an extra route that caused the problem.

Comment: ...`Temp;C:`  does this not look suspicious to you?

Answer (score 1):

So for some reason I had an extra directory on my "TEMP" in my environment variables (Windows). The solution was to remove the extra directory and restart the command line tool